# All our problems would/will go away from us

Tags: subjunctives

> All our problems would go away from us, if we stop judging people so
> much.
>
> All our problems will go away from us, if we stop judging people so
> much.

How the the application of "would" and "will" change the meaning of the sentence?

Comment: **Would** makes this statement tentative and less stronger. It's a way of hedge.

Comment: *would* induces probability and compare to that, *will* reflects a bit more surety.

Comment: The problem with the *would* version is that it doesn't fit well in your sentence. It's better to stick with the *will* version. If you want to use *would* there, you should use *stopped* instead. Also, *problems go way from us* isn't quite idiomatic. (I think it's better without *from us*.)

Comment: I agree with Damkerng T. The use of would in an if clause should in most cases be used with the verb in the simple past. This is if clause type 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"would"** suggests that the situation mentioned in the hypothesis is less probable or impossible to happen.On the other hand, the future tense suggests that what is stated can happen in the future.
  eg:**If we work hard, we will finish the project on time**. (It can happen)
     **If we worked hard, we would finish the project on time.** (But it's highly likely that we won't because we're not working hard enough)

Answer (score 0):

If I travel, will you come too?

The travel sounds like a real situation with a high probability of happening.

If I travelled, would you come too?

Here it sounds like a perhaps idea... Like you are just pondering the idea of travelling.

Hope this helps.